# Can I link two Twitter accounts to my Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have two Twitter accounts - two different emails. I want to have each post tweets to their own related Facebook pages I am admin of. Twitter won't let me have the second Twitter account post to its related page, which I set up as a separate business page after Twitter wouldn't let me post to a second page under my profile. Help, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Transfer the second Facebook Page to the "ownership" of a different (and, if necessary, newly-created) Facebook account.

Technically, creating this second Facebook account for a fictitious person would violate Facebook's TOS, and so you can/should create this second account as a "[business account](https://www.facebook.com/help/131976240210052)" (with a dummy and not-yet-published Page, if necessary).

After the second Facebook account will "like" your second Page, your original account can add the second account as an additional admin, and then remove itself from being an admin.

At this point, there will no longer be any connection between the second Page and your original account, and Twitter should not have any reason to complain.  (Before logging into Twitter, make sure your original account is logged out of Facebook.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Third Party solutions out there, but so far the best one I've encountered is zapier.com.

You can set up multiple twitter accounts to post to one Facebook feed, or one twitter to multiple pages. It's pretty incredible.